# Setting up PHP FTP functions

Tags: linux, php, ftp

According to the docs I must reinstall PHP in order to get PHP FTP support: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ftp.installation.php

Is this correct?  Is there no way I could just enable a mode or put an extra parameter somewhere?  My server runs a live environment :-\

OS:  SUSE Linux

Comment: Tell us your operating system.

Comment: Doh!  Sorry I missed that hugely important detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in SuSE you can install the FTP module for PHP with

```
zypper install php5-ftp
```

Then just restart Apache.

Comment: How come the docs don't mention anything about this?  So apparently you don't have to install it at the same time as PHP

Comment: PHP docs are generally for developers and do not tell a word about how to install foo in operating system bar; that detail is left to user/admin of OS bar :)